# How to import specific svn branch to existing git repo using svn2git?

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

How can I import a specific branch in my SVN repo to another existing GIT repo?
ex. svn/my-branch --> git/my-branch

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by doing something like (see: [here](http://ivanz.com/2009/01/15/selective-import-of-svn-branches-into-a-gitgit-svn-repository/) for more details):

1. Define the new branch in .git/config :

   ```
   [svn-remote "release-branch"]
      url = svn+ssh://user@example.com/source/branches/branch_name
      fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn-release-branch
   ```
2. Import the SVN branch. SVN_BRANCHED_REVISION is the the revision when the branch happened in SVN.

   ```
   git svn fetch release-branch -r SVN_BRANCHED_REVISION
   ```

In order to establish the SVN_BRANCHED_REVISION value you can use:

```
  svn log --stop-on-copy PATH_TO_BRANCH
```

3. Hook up a local Git branch to the remote branch:

   ```
   git branch --track release git-svn-release
   ```
4. Checkout and update

   ```
   git checkout release
   git svn rebase
   ```